# Why are ReferencedSymbol's Locations empty?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to find all references in a solution to specific symbol, but Locations property is always empty. I load stand alone project, find symbol I am looking for and then ask compilation to give me all references to a symbol. I get one reference (correct, as there is only one attribute usage), but Locations property is empty. Here is the code

```
IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject(projectPath);

var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

var searchAttributeName = typeof(OneToOneAttribute).FullName;

var project = solution.Projects.First();

var compilation = project.GetCompilation();

var attSymbol = (NamedTypeSymbol)compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(searchAttributeName);

var references = attSymbol.FindReferences(solution);

    foreach (ReferencedSymbol referencedSymbol in references)
    {
        foreach (ReferenceLocation location in referencedSymbol.Locations)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: To check, what does compilation.GetDiagnostics() give you? Are there compile errors or something else that indicates your project didn't load fine?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: I get five errors, reference missing. So If I understand this, even though project has references and compiles, when loaded like this, I have to manually add them?

Comment: This is probably an issue with LoadStandAloneProject. Have you considered loading the full solution that contains your project?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Yes, later I will be loading the solution, this is just a prototype and I just moved attribute definition into a project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was discussed in the comments, LoadStandAloneProject wasn't creating your project references properly. The proper fix was to use LoadSolution.